# NavigationLink automatically pop

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigation, navigationview

I am developing a list navigation app with SwiftUI.
A navigation bug occurred in the code and procedure shown below.

1.tap item in FirstView.
2.open SecondView.
3.open ThirdView.
4.tap next button navigate to SecondView.

Repeat steps 2-4 about 10 times navigate SecondView when pop View to FirstView.

How can I solve it?

sample code

```
import SwiftUI

final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentIndex: Int?
    
    public func next() {
        if let currentIndex = self.currentIndex {
           if currentIndex < 100 {
               self.currentIndex = currentIndex + 1
           } else {
               self.currentIndex = nil
           }
        }
    }
}

struct FirstView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(0..<100) { i in
                NavigationLink(String(i),
                               tag: i,
                               selection: $vm.currentIndex) {
                    SecondView(vm: vm)
                }.isDetailLink(false)
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        .navigationTitle("First View")
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink("go to third") {
                ThirdView(vm: vm)
            }.isDetailLink(false)
            
            if let currentIndex = vm.currentIndex {
                Text("currentIndex: \(currentIndex)")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Second View")
    }
}

struct ThirdView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: vm.next) {
                Text("next")
            }
            if let currentIndex = vm.currentIndex {
                Text("currentIndex: \(currentIndex)")
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Third View")
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the bug that occurs vs expected output?

Comment: Xcode Version 13.2.1 (13C100)
iOS15.2
Swift5

If repeat the navigation about 10 times, it will return FirstView automatically.

The expected output is to move from 0 to 100 with the next button.

Comment: This reads like a bad implementation of a view router navigation pattern. What are you trying to accomplish with the code you are providing? It almost feels like you are running up against the @ViewBuilder 10 view limit...